# Margin on right side of site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this small white margin on the right side of a website I'm building with Bootstrap 3. It gets especially pronounced on mobile.

Tried checking margins, padding, floats in CSS. Can't figure out what's wrong :(
Any ideas?

Site
www.solocam.me

Image of problem
http://snag.gy/VL2mD.jpg

Comment: HTML http://www.codeshare.io/spcPO

Comment: CSS http://www.codeshare.io/Yy7lp

Comment: Please add the relevant code into the question. Or better still a link to the live stie, then we can debug that.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I did everything you mentioned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div class="row">` right after the `<!-- Contact Form - START -->` comment is what's throwing the margin off. It looks like if you removed the `margin-right: -15px;` from that "row", it should fix it.

Comment: Thanks Justin :) There was an extra </div> at that section and this was what caused the problem. How did you know?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, and I'm glad it helped you. I just viewed the inspector, did process of elimination until I found it. I removed elements from the DOM until the extra margin disappeared, then I drilled into that section.

Answer (score 1):

under your div banner there is a div row, the css to that has a margin-right.Change that to 0 will solve it.

Comment: I accepeted Justin's answer. It was a bit more percise. But how did you know it was that row's fault?

Comment: He literally just copied my answer...Anyways, when you inspect element with chrome, you can delete each div till the margin is gone, then you will know which div has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

either on the body or specifically on the div with the blank space